# Disable installs/downloads of app in Android 14 temporarily

Tags: android, google-play, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-14

My app is in production, which has a feature of communicating with peripheral device using Ble, we are facing issues with new Android version(14), Is there a way that I can stop installs or downloads for users with Android 14 temporarily while we fix the peripheral issue.

Comment: Have you seen: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6346149?hl=en#zippy=%2Chalt-a-staged-rollout

Comment: Hey Morrison, thanks for your response. I don't see anything that restricts based on version in there, I know we can restrict specific device models. Did I miss something?

Comment: I'm not aware of any version restriction on the halt. Probably due to the issue with bad apk installed on Android 13 and then user updates to Android 14 afterwards, apk still broken, what does user do now?

Comment: Not sure, But My team is working on fixing the peripheral, Meanwhile I don't want my app to be installed on Android 14, anything that I can do to disable installs  only for latest android version.